# What lens should I use for my Raspberry Pi?

Tags: photography

I am building myself a camera that attaches to the back of my Celestron NexStar 4 SE telescope and I am not sure what type of lens to choose to replace the stock lens on the Raspberry Pi camera. I bought [this](http://www.m12lenses.com/CS-Mount-Lens-Holder-Metal-p/pt-lh013csm.htm) CS Mount and by mistake bought M12 lenses thinking it was a mount for M12 lenses but now I know CS mounts require bigger lenses than M12. So should I instead get a M12 mount and use M12 lenses or should I buy a CS lens and what kind if I am looking to do a high quality video/live stream?

Raspberry Pi Camera: https://www.adafruit.com/products/3099

Answer (score 3):

Thought I would revisit this and answer my own question...no lens is needed at all :)

The telescope itself is the lens, so once that finally made sense to me I then took the lens off the Raspberry Pi camera and I can now use the camera with the telescope

[image]

Comment: Congratulations!  Technically you could keep the lens on, and refocus it to a plane close in front, and then place the camera behind the telescope so that the front focal plane of the lens coincided with the focal plane of the telescope. But I can't think of any reason why that would be a good thing to do. Your solution is definitely the simplest.